# Quais são os sufixos de versões NPM e o que fazem?

Tags: node.js, versionamento, npm

Em ambiente Node.js quando vamos buscar módulos à [*NPM*](https://www.npmjs.com/) pode usar-se sufixos para especificar versões.

Por exemplo, no `package.json` vejo muitas vezes:

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "~1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
```

O que são estes sufixos `^`, `~`, e como se usam?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aqui fica uma lista para quem precisar, e partindo de o pressuposto que as versões indicadas respeitam a norma de versionamento [SEMVER](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/)<sup>*****</sup>:

<sub>Vou usar `1.2.3` somente como *exemplo* de versão</sub>

- `~1.2.3` "versão aproximada". Vai manter a versão *menor*, ou seja só permite mudancas no ultimo parametro do versionamento. Ou seja: `1.2` e `>=3` no ultimo parâmetro.
- `^1.2.3` "compatível com" Vai aceitar mudança de versões menores, mas não permite versões novas (primeiro parâmetro). Ou seja: `1` e `>=2.>=3` nos ultimos parâmetros.
- `1.2.3` Versão exata.
- `>1.2.3` Maior que...
- `>=1.2.3` Maior ou igual...
- `<1.2.3` Menor que...
- `<=1.2.3` Menor ou igual...
- `1.2.x` 1.2.0, 1.2.1, etc., mas não 1.3.0. (quase semelhante a `~1.2.3`)
- `http://url.com/tarball` Passando um *url* é possivel instalar um *tarball*, por exemplo do Github para casos em que o pacote/software não se encontre publicado na NPM. Por exemplo no Github seria algo asim: `https://github.com/contaGithub/nomeProjeto/tarball/master`
- `*` *wildcard*, aceita qualquer versão.

> ***** - [*SEMVER* é um modelo de versionamento](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/), para facilitar prever se as mudanças entre versões de um software são grandes, pequenas ou somente correções. O modelo SEMVER consiste em três partes, numéricas que são/representam respetivamente alterações ao software de carácter: `maior`, `menor`, `correção`.