# Como ver todos os módulos instalados no nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Estou dando uma fuçada no nodejs e gostaria de saber como faço para listar todos os módulos que instalei.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)? mas deves saber isso do teu `package.json` não?

Comment: @Sergio, nem sei do que você está falando. Realmente eu estou começando agora agora mesmo no nodejs

Comment: @Sergio, esse aí exibiu um tanto de parada. Bota na resposta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os módulos que instalas devem estar configurados no `package.json -> "dependencies"` seguindo as regras para [nomes e sufixos de versionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85532/129) de cada modulo.

Aí defines todos os programas que o teu projeto precisa e instalas tudo correndo

```
npm install
```

Para saberes/confirmares o que está instalado e qual a versão podes usar [`$ npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) que te dá uma lista desses programas e também das suas depêndências.

Um exemplo de resultado desse `npm list` seria assim:

```
projeto@2.3.0 C:\Users\Sergio\GitHub\projeto
├─┬ agent@0.2.1
│ ├── mout@0.9.1
│ └── prime@0.4.2
├── async@1.4.2
├─┬ body-parser@1.13.3
│ ├── bytes@2.1.0
│ ├── content-type@1.0.1
│ ├── depd@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ http-errors@1.3.1
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ └── statuses@1.2.1
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.11
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
│ ├── qs@4.0.0
│ ├─┬ raw-body@2.1.4
│ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.12
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
│ └─┬ type-is@1.6.9
│   ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│   └─┬ mime-types@2.1.7
│     └── mime-db@1.19.0
// etc
```

Comment: E como faço para listar apenas um determinado pacote ?

Comment: @MikeOtharan Se estiver no linux pode modificar a saída com grep, ficaria assim ```npm list | grep nome_do_modulo``` e para listar sem as dependências é só usar ```npm list  --depth=0```